# Querying dates with different timezones at db and application level

Tags: mariadb, datetime, timezone

There is a `created_at` column of `datetime` type in the `order` table. In my application I'm storing dates to the db as datetime in UTC. When I bring them back from the db I'm presenting/formating them to the user as 'America/Tijuana'. Hence user input is expected in that timezone.

I'm very new to SQL programming, in fact I'm using the framework's integrated query building methods. Anyway, for "debugging" is what I am manually trying in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE date(`created_at`) LIKE '%somedate%'
```

It works, but is comparing against UTC datetimes in the db. I want it to compare to 'America/Tijuana'.

I'm trying

```
SELECT * FROM `order` 
  WHERE date(convert_tz(`created_at`, 'UTC', 'America/tijuana')) LIKE '%30%'
```

which runs, but return 0 values. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @horse hi, mariadb

Comment: You are incorrectly applying the `LIKE` predicate, intended to compare strings, do a `datetime` value.

Comment: @mustaccio it is possible to apply LIKE to dates, they just get converted to the string representation. It is not very effective but it should work.

Comment: @jkavalik thank you I'm aware of implicit casting. It _could_ work only if you guarantee the default date format remains constant. Try changing `LC_TIME`.

Comment: Thank sir, type conversion was in my head as something that might be a potential issue. I'll use datetime instead as sugested.

Comment: Keep in mind that any function run against a column in the `WHERE` clause is going to produce a [non-sargable query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  It's better to convert the right-hand side to UTC, then use that to query the column directly.  Think about it - otherwise you literally have to convert every column in your table.  The more rows you have in the table, the slower the query will be.

Comment: @mustaccio I did not find that mentioned in the manual, only [`lc_time_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) which won't be used for the implicit casting afaik, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: @Matt I knew a conversion needed to take place, I didn't think It made a difference the place (app or db). I'll look iinto this.

Comment: [See here for examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/634824) WRT sargability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT created_at,
convert_tz(created_at , '+00:00', '-07:00'),
convert_tz(created_at , 'UTC', 'America/tijuana')
FROM 
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 09:26:50' as created_at FROM DUAL) orders;
```

If the last column is null , see prerequisites at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/convert_tz/

Comment: you were correct. I added the timezone tables, thanks.

Comment: @user1236524, you may mark it as an answer.